# Archinstall keeps giving me: "Can not find block device: /dev/sda1"

Tags: arch-linux

Here is the install log:

```
Hardware model detected: innotek GmbH VirtualBox; UEFI mode: False
Processor model detected: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-3240 CPU @ 3.40GHz
Memory statistics: 705312 available out of 989064 total installed
Virtualization detected: oracle; is VM: True
Graphics devices detected: dict_keys(['VMware SVGA II Adapter'])
Disk states before installing: [
    {
        "children": [],
        "fsavail": 0,
        "fsroots": [
            "."
        ],
        "fstype": "squashfs",
        "fsuse_percentage": "100%",
        "fsver": "4.0",
        "log_sec": 512,
        "mountpoint": "/run/archiso/airootfs",
        "mountpoints": [
            "/run/archiso/airootfs"
        ],
        "name": "loop0",
        "parttype": null,
        "partuuid": null,
        "path": "/dev/loop0",
        "pkname": null,
        "pttype": null,
        "ptuuid": null,
        "rota": true,
        "size": "673 MiB",
        "tran": null,
        "type": "loop",
        "uuid": null
    },
    {
        "children": [],
        "fsavail": null,
        "fsroots": [],
        "fstype": null,
        "fsuse_percentage": null,
        "fsver": null,
        "log_sec": 512,
        "mountpoint": null,
        "mountpoints": [],
        "name": "sda",
        "parttype": null,
        "partuuid": null,
        "path": "/dev/sda",
        "pkname": null,
        "pttype": null,
        "ptuuid": null,
        "rota": true,
        "size": "40960 MiB",
        "tran": "sata",
        "type": "disk",
        "uuid": null
    },
    {
        "children": [],
        "fsavail": 0,
        "fsroots": [
            "."
        ],
        "fstype": "iso9660",
        "fsuse_percentage": "100%",
        "fsver": "Joliet Extension",
        "log_sec": 2048,
        "mountpoint": "/run/archiso/bootmnt",
        "mountpoints": [
            "/run/archiso/bootmnt"
        ],
        "name": "sr0",
        "parttype": null,
        "partuuid": null,
        "path": "/dev/sr0",
        "pkname": null,
        "pttype": "dos",
        "ptuuid": "5cfcc5eb",
        "rota": true,
        "size": "793 MiB",
        "tran": "ata",
        "type": "rom",
        "uuid": "2023-08-01-12-17-20-00"
    }
]
Testing connectivity to the Arch Linux mirrors...
Password strength: very weak
Importing profile: /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/archinstall/default_profiles/__init__.py
Importing profile: /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/archinstall/default_profiles/custom.py
Importing profile: /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/archinstall/default_profiles/desktop.py
Importing profile: /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/archinstall/default_profiles/minimal.py
Importing profile: /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/archinstall/default_profiles/server.py
Importing profile: /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/archinstall/default_profiles/tailored.py
Importing profile: /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/archinstall/default_profiles/xorg.py
Importing profile: /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/archinstall/default_profiles/applications/__init__.py
Importing profile: /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/archinstall/default_profiles/applications/pipewire.py
Importing profile: /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/archinstall/default_profiles/desktops/__init__.py
Importing profile: /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/archinstall/default_profiles/desktops/awesome.py
Importing profile: /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/archinstall/default_profiles/desktops/bspwm.py
Importing profile: /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/archinstall/default_profiles/desktops/budgie.py
Importing profile: /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/archinstall/default_profiles/desktops/cinnamon.py
Importing profile: /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/archinstall/default_profiles/desktops/cutefish.py
Importing profile: /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/archinstall/default_profiles/desktops/deepin.py
Importing profile: /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/archinstall/default_profiles/desktops/enlightenment.py
Importing profile: /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/archinstall/default_profiles/desktops/gnome.py
Importing profile: /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/archinstall/default_profiles/desktops/hyperland.py
Importing profile: /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/archinstall/default_profiles/desktops/i3.py
Importing profile: /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/archinstall/default_profiles/desktops/kde.py
Importing profile: /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/archinstall/default_profiles/desktops/lxqt.py
Importing profile: /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/archinstall/default_profiles/desktops/mate.py
Importing profile: /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/archinstall/default_profiles/desktops/qtile.py
Importing profile: /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/archinstall/default_profiles/desktops/sway.py
Cannot import <module 'sway' from '/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/archinstall/default_profiles/desktops/sway.py'>, it does not appear to be a Profile class
Importing profile: /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/archinstall/default_profiles/desktops/xfce4.py
Importing profile: /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/archinstall/default_profiles/servers/__init__.py
Importing profile: /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/archinstall/default_profiles/servers/cockpit.py
Importing profile: /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/archinstall/default_profiles/servers/docker.py
Importing profile: /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/archinstall/default_profiles/servers/httpd.py
Importing profile: /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/archinstall/default_profiles/servers/lighttpd.py
Importing profile: /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/archinstall/default_profiles/servers/mariadb.py
Importing profile: /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/archinstall/default_profiles/servers/nginx.py
Importing profile: /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/archinstall/default_profiles/servers/postgresql.py
Importing profile: /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/archinstall/default_profiles/servers/sshd.py
Importing profile: /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/archinstall/default_profiles/servers/tomcat.py
Password strength: very weak
Password strength: very weak
 -- Chosen configuration --
{
    "__separator__": null,
    "additional-repositories": [],
    "archinstall-language": "English",
    "audio_config": {
        "audio": "pulseaudio"
    },
    "bootloader": "Grub",
    "config_version": "2.6.0",
    "debug": false,
    "disk_config": {
        "config_type": "default_layout",
        "device_modifications": [
            {
                "device": "/dev/sda",
                "partitions": [
                    {
                        "btrfs": [],
                        "flags": [
                            "Boot"
                        ],
                        "fs_type": "fat32",
                        "length": {
                            "sector_size": null,
                            "total_size": null,
                            "unit": "MiB",
                            "value": 203
                        },
                        "mount_options": [],
                        "mountpoint": "/boot",
                        "obj_id": "1f773698-26ae-45dd-9c13-d802646d3344",
                        "start": {
                            "sector_size": null,
                            "total_size": null,
                            "unit": "MiB",
                            "value": 3
                        },
                        "status": "create",
                        "type": "primary"
                    },
                    {
                        "btrfs": [],
                        "flags": [],
                        "fs_type": "ext4",
                        "length": {
                            "sector_size": null,
                            "total_size": null,
                            "unit": "GiB",
                            "value": 20
                        },
                        "mount_options": [],
                        "mountpoint": "/",
                        "obj_id": "37adec5c-a8ce-4fda-b772-50ca761a6e3b",
                        "start": {
                            "sector_size": null,
                            "total_size": null,
                            "unit": "MiB",
                            "value": 206
                        },
                        "status": "create",
                        "type": "primary"
                    },
                    {
                        "btrfs": [],
                        "flags": [],
                        "fs_type": "ext4",
                        "length": {
                            "sector_size": null,
                            "total_size": {
                                "sector_size": null,
                                "total_size": null,
                                "unit": "B",
                                "value": 42949672960
                            },
                            "unit": "Percent",
                            "value": 100
                        },
                        "mount_options": [],
                        "mountpoint": "/home",
                        "obj_id": "b2185501-6b9b-4055-b96c-1db64664de7e",
                        "start": {
                            "sector_size": null,
                            "total_size": null,
                            "unit": "GiB",
                            "value": 20
                        },
                        "status": "create",
                        "type": "primary"
                    }
                ],
                "wipe": true
            }
        ]
    },
    "disk_encryption": null,
    "hostname": "archlinux",
    "kernels": [
        "linux"
    ],
    "locale_config": {
        "kb_layout": "it",
        "sys_enc": "UTF-8",
        "sys_lang": "en_US"
    },
    "mirror_config": {
        "custom_mirrors": [],
        "mirror_regions": {
            "Italy": [
                "https://archmirror.it/repos/$repo/os/$arch",
                "http://archlinux.mirror.garr.it/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch"
            ]
        }
    },
    "network_config": {
        "type": "nm"
    },
    "no_pkg_lookups": false,
    "ntp": true,
    "offline": false,
    "packages": [
        "firefox"
    ],
    "parallel downloads": 0,
    "profile_config": {
        "gfx_driver": "All open-source",
        "greeter": "lightdm",
        "profile": {
            "custom_settings": {
                "i3-wm": {}
            },
            "details": [
                "i3-wm"
            ],
            "main": "Desktop"
        }
    },
    "save_config": null,
    "script": "guided",
    "silent": false,
    "swap": true,
    "timezone": "Europe/Berlin",
    "version": "2.6.0"
}
Unmounting all partitions: /dev/sda
Wiping partitions and metadata: /dev/sda
Creating partitions: /dev/sda
    Type: primary
    Filesystem: fat32
    Geometry: 6144 start sector, 415744 length
Calling partprobe: partprobe /dev/sda1
Partprobe was not able to inform the kernel of the new disk state (ignoring error): ['/usr/bin/partprobe', '/dev/sda1'] exited with abnormal exit code [1]: : Partition(s) 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64 on /dev/sda1 have been written, but we have been unable to inform the kernel of the change, probably because it/they are in use.  As a result, the old partition(s) will remain in use.  You should reboot now before making further changes.

partuuid found: {'name': 'sda1', 'path': '/dev/sda1', 'pkname': 'sda', 'size': '203 MiB', 'log_sec': 512, 'pttype': 'dos', 'ptuuid': 'a9a88a20', 'rota': True, 'tran': None, 'partuuid': 'a9a88a20-01', 'parttype': '0xb', 'uuid': None, 'fstype': None, 'fsver': None, 'fsavail': None, 'fsuse_percentage': None, 'type': 'part', 'mountpoint': None, 'mountpoints': [], 'fsroots': [], 'children': []}
    Type: primary
    Filesystem: ext4
    Geometry: 421888 start sector, 41943040 length
Calling partprobe: partprobe /dev/sda2
Partprobe was not able to inform the kernel of the new disk state (ignoring error): ['/usr/bin/partprobe', '/dev/sda2'] exited with abnormal exit code [1]: : Partition(s) 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64 on /dev/sda2 have been written, but we have been unable to inform the kernel of the change, probably because it/they are in use.  As a result, the old partition(s) will remain in use.  You should reboot now before making further changes.

partuuid found: {'name': 'sda2', 'path': '/dev/sda2', 'pkname': 'sda', 'size': '20400 MiB', 'log_sec': 512, 'pttype': 'dos', 'ptuuid': 'a9a88a20', 'rota': True, 'tran': None, 'partuuid': 'a9a88a20-02', 'parttype': '0x83', 'uuid': None, 'fstype': None, 'fsver': None, 'fsavail': None, 'fsuse_percentage': None, 'type': 'part', 'mountpoint': None, 'mountpoints': [], 'fsroots': [], 'children': []}
    Type: primary
    Filesystem: ext4
    Geometry: 41943040 start sector, 42949672960 length
Calling partprobe: partprobe /dev/sda3
Partprobe was not able to inform the kernel of the new disk state (ignoring error): ['/usr/bin/partprobe', '/dev/sda3'] exited with abnormal exit code [1]: : Partition(s) 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64 on /dev/sda3 have been written, but we have been unable to inform the kernel of the change, probably because it/they are in use.  As a result, the old partition(s) will remain in use.  You should reboot now before making further changes.

partuuid found: {'name': 'sda3', 'path': '/dev/sda3', 'pkname': 'sda', 'size': '20145 MiB', 'log_sec': 512, 'pttype': 'dos', 'ptuuid': 'a9a88a20', 'rota': True, 'tran': None, 'partuuid': 'a9a88a20-03', 'parttype': '0x83', 'uuid': None, 'fstype': None, 'fsver': None, 'fsavail': None, 'fsuse_percentage': None, 'type': 'part', 'mountpoint': None, 'mountpoints': [], 'fsroots': [], 'children': []}
Calling partprobe: partprobe /dev/sda
Unmounting all partitions: /dev/sda
Formatting filesystem: /usr/bin/mkfs.fat -F32 /dev/sda1
Formatting filesystem: /usr/bin/mkfs.ext4 -F /dev/sda2
Formatting filesystem: /usr/bin/mkfs.ext4 -F /dev/sda3
Starting installation
Mounting partitions in order
Mounting /dev/sda2: command
Mounting /dev/sda1: command
Mounting /dev/sda3: command
Waiting for time sync (systemd-timesyncd.service) to complete.
Waiting for automatic mirror selection (reflector) to complete.
Waiting for Arch Linux keyring sync (archlinux-keyring-wkd-sync) to complete.
A new package mirror-list has been created: /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist
The multilib flag is not set. This system will be installed without multilib repositories enabled.
The testing flag is not set. This system will be installed without testing repositories enabled.
Installing packages: ['base', 'base-devel', 'linux-firmware', 'linux', 'grub']
Enabling periodic TRIM
Enabling service fstrim.timer
A new package mirror-list has been created: /mnt/archinstall/etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist
Setting up swap on zram
Installing packages: ['zram-generator']
Enabling service systemd-zram-setup@zram0.service
Adding bootloader Grub to /dev/sda1
Installing packages: ['grub']
GRUB boot partition: /dev/sda1
Can not find block device: /dev/sda1
```

I have tried deleting the virtual machine, making a new one and reusing Archinstall but it gives me that error and "Partprobe was not able to inform the kernel of the new disk state" every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced this same issue today while trying to install on my Proxmox server. Turning off secure boot in the VM bios got me past the error. YMMV but I hope this helps.